# TypeInitialization Exception

Tags: c#, exception, types, byte

I have the following program in C#

Basically, the program is throwing a `TypeInitializationException`.  I believe that the culprit is this line:

```
static byte[] buffer = ToByteArray("Hello, this is a test message");
```

I tried changing the static fields and the like but it is still giving me errors.  What can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: the actual stacktrace would be a nice addition to your question

Comment: Is it legal to convert a byte array to a byte? Seems odd (doesn't make sense)... I dunno

Comment: Have you checked on the length of the byte-array before the method returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have error in `ToByteArray` implementation in this fragment `Convert.ToByte(CharArray)`. Use next code to convert string to array of bytes in `Unicode` encoding. Feel free to change  encoding to whatever you find acceptable and useful in `Encoding` class, including `ASCII` and `UTF-8`

```
public static byte[] ToByteArray(string StringToConvert)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(StringToConvert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem,

```
ByteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(CharArray);
```

use

```
ByteArray[i] = Convert.ToByte(CharArray[i]);
```